# Perl Module - MIME::Lite::TT::HTML, is sending HTML content as an attachment

Tags: perl, email, mime

Here is a snippet from my Perl script:

```
my %params = (
  sub_name            => $sub_name, 
  asm_name            => $asm_name,
  zsm                 => $zsm,
  store               => $store,
  pin                 => $pin,
  tier                => $tier,
  avg_weekly_all      => $avg_weekly_all,
  avg_weekly_br       => $avg_weekly_brakes,
  expected_sales      => $expected_sales,
  numOfBays           => $numOfBays,
  numOfTechs          => $numOfTechs,
  estimatedJobs       => $estimatedBrakeJobs,
  brand               => $brand,
  qty                 => $qty
);

my %options = (INCLUDE_PATH => '.');

my $msg = MIME::Lite::TT::HTML->new(
  From        => 'xxx.xxxx@somecompany.com',
  To          => 'me@somecompany.com',
  Subject     => "Request (MSG ID: $id)",
  Template    => { html => 'edge14.html.tt' },
  TmplOptions => \%options,
  TmplParams  => \%params
);

$msg->attr("content-type" => "multipart/mixed");

$msg->attach(
  Type => 'text/csv',
  Path => 'out.txt',
  Filename => "brake_lift_$id" . ".csv",
  Disposition => 'attachment'
);

$msg->send or die "Unable to send message: $!";
```

It is sending the email (with attachment) just fine, but it is not rendering the html content in the body of the email. It is sending as plain text and attaching the html in the format "ATT00001..htm", yes that's TWO dots before 'htm'...

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: You'll get the ATT0001 which means attachment error.  The email headers, body or email attachment config options are wrong.  The interpreters change to be more strict so what worked years ago needs different configuration. See here for examples:   https://web.archive.org/web/20200418192720/https://www.akadia.com/services/email_attachments_using_perl.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered my own question! Noticed that ALL of the other hash attributes were barewords, so I took the quotes off of "content-type" and it works like a charm!